# Arrow are not in place

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

This is a simple graph with multi-nodes those originate from a single center point. I have drawn it, but they arrows are not from a single point. What wrong with this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[minimum height=0pt, minimum width=0pt] (mid) at (0,0) {};
    \node (a) [above=1cm of mid] {1};
    \node (b) [above left=1cm of mid] {2};
    \node (c) [above right=1cm of mid] {3};
    \node (d) [below=1cm of mid] {4};
    \node (e) [below left=1cm of mid] {5};
    \node (f) [below right=1cm of mid] {6};
    \draw (mid) to (a);
    \draw (mid) to (b);
    \draw (mid) to (c);
    \draw (mid) to (d);
    \draw (mid) to (e);
    \draw (mid) to (f);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Even with minimum width and height to 0pt, the node contains an "inner sep" with certain value. If you need an empty node (a point) use a `coordinate`.

Comment: @Ignasi I tried, but I am not flexible with coordinate.

Comment: `\node[inner sep=0pt] (mid) at (0,0) {};` or `\coordinate (mid) at (0,0);` and here you go ;)

Comment: @SebGlav Thanks a bunch. Great!